# What is the reduced row echelon form of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

Let $$A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
7 & 7 & 9 & -17\\
6 & 6 & 1 & -2 \\
-12 & -12 & -27 & 1 \\
7& 7 & 17 & -15\end{array} \right)$$

1. What is the reduced row echelon form of $A$?
2. What is the rank of $A$?

Comment: click edit to see how to write matrix in a clear way

Comment: Surely $rank A \leq 3$ because the first two columns are equal

Comment: To help us help you: Do you know what *reduced row echelon form* and *rank* mean?  Do you know what an *elementary row operation* is?

Answer (score 2):

$1.$ Multiply the first row by $\frac{1}{7}:$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
6 & 6 & 1 & -2 \\ 
-12 & -12 & -27 & 1 \\ 
7 & 7 & 17 & -15 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$2.$ Multiply first row by $6$ and add to row $2$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{47}{7} & \frac{88}{7} \\ 
-12 & -12 & -27 & 1 \\ 
7 & 7 & 17 & -15 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
$3.$ Multiply first row by $12$ to the third row:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{47}{7} & \frac{88}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{81}{7} & -\frac{197}{7} \\ 
7 & 7 & 17 & -15
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$4.$ Multiply first row by $-7$ and add to the fourth row:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{47}{7} & \frac{88}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{81}{7} & -\frac{197}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 8 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$5.$ Multiply the second row by $-\frac{7}{47}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{88}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & -\frac{81}{7} & -\frac{197}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 8 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$6.$ Multiply second row by $\frac{81}{7}$ and add to the third row:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{88}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2341}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & 8 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$7.$ Multiply the second row by $-8$ to the fourth row:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{88}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{-2341}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{798}{47}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$8.$ Multiply the third row by $-\frac{47}{2341}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{88}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{798}{47} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$9.$ Multiply the third row by $-\frac{798}{47}$ and add to the fourth row:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{88}{47} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is the row echelon form. For the reduced row echelon form, 
$10.$ Multiply the third row by $\frac{88}{47}$ and add to the second row to get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & -\frac{17}{7} \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
$11.$ Multiply the third row by $\frac{17}{7}$ and add it to the first row to get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{9}{7} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$12.$ Multiply the second row by $-\frac{9}{7}$ and add it to the first row to get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This has rank $3$ (ie, the number of non-zero rows).